# How to subscribe to tags?

Tags: support, newsletter

I am interested in answering questions related to C#, Entity Framework and other Microsoft technologies. Is there a way for me to receive an email every day with lists of questions for each tag or keyword?

Answer (score 74):

Just go to the [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) page on the Stack Exchange site, and you can subscribe to tags across different sites over the network. You can set it to email you for the tags that you filter for as well.

Comment: How can I remove already created filters?

Comment: Possible to filter and subscribe to questions that contain two tags at the same time? Like [reactjs] AND [css]

Comment: @checho: Edit the filter -- there is a link at the bottom to delete it.

Answer (score 34):

You can also just search for the tag here https://stackoverflow.com/tags
and then hover over the desired tag and then click subscribe.

[image: stack overflow subscribe popup]

Comment: I don't see the subscrible link anymore. I believe the interface design has changed.

Comment: I havent received an email for a week on my subscriptions, I wonder if that service has ended

Comment: This answer no longer seems to apply. Only the `rss` option is present. Is subscribing by email deprecated?

Comment: @bmacnaughton Any news from it ?

Comment: Any news from this ?

Comment: +1. This still works. However, "Subscribe" is now "Watch Tag".

Comment: But watching a tag is not the same as actually getting email notifications, right?

Answer (score 20):

If you want to just subscribe to tags with an rss reader rather than get emails you can do something like the following:

`[stack exchange site]/feeds/tag/[your tag name](+[and|or]+[second tag name])`

For me, since I wanted to get a feed for the `android-layout` tag I did

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android-layout

You can also use the AND and OR operators by including `+and+` and `+or+` between the tag names. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android-layout+and+relativelayout

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android+or+ios+or+java+or+swift

Just enter addresses like these into your feed reader and you are good to go.

See also https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Comment: You can get new answers per email, SMS, push notification or anything else by creating connecting the StackOverflow's RSS feed to them using an IFTTT recipe, e.g. "If a new Google Play question is posted on Stack Overflow, send me an email."

Comment: I use https://blogtrottr.com/ and works like a charm!