# Is subscribing to a tag by email deprecated?

Tags: support, tags, email, subscriptions

An old answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254318/how-to-subscribe-to-tags) shows the "subscribe" option shown on this image as the way in which to subscribe to email notifications for a tag:

[image]

The email option is no longer present. Is there another way to subscribe via email?

Either way, it seems that the old answers are no longer valid.

Comment: Another way is described in another answer to the same question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254318/how-to-subscribe-to-tags#254327

Comment: I'm not sure if people who are already subscribed to tags are even getting emails, since someone said they weren't [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375089/6083675).

Comment: @Laurel - I am still getting emails. That's what reminded me to try to add some more relevant tags for my current work.

Comment: IIRC, basically, yes. When they made the change to the new tag-popup they removed a bunch of capability. What I recall being said was that the subscribe functionality was intentionally removed, with maybe something else in the future. You might want to check the meta announcing the change in the tag popup.