# Bring back easy tag subscriptions (email updates)

Tags: feature-request, email, tag-watching, subscriptions

In the past, subscribing to email updates for new questions based on tags was easy via a 'subscribe' link on the

[image: subscribe to a tag]

See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336515/5219886) for instructions.

This link is now gone, and people are [asking if it has been deprecated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375752/is-subscribing-to-a-tag-by-email-deprecated), which appears to be the case.

I use and love this feature.

I'm voting with this request to bring it back.

I have noticed that it may be the intention to replace subscriptions with notifications based on the new '[tag watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching)' feature. There is [some discussion to this effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312247/447264) but it has been six months :(

Comment: With 6 months it is just at the start of the  [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) window things normally happen here ...

Comment: What about using an RSS feed service that can send emails to you? Perhaps not as simple as a direct email subscription, but assuming this feature is not brought back, that is always an option.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed . I could do this, but it is not easy. It is still possible to use email subscriptions (the instructions I reference point to [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) page on the Stack Exchange site which does this), it is just nowhere near as convenient.