# Has the email notification based on tag feature been removed?

Tags: support, tags, notifications, email

I received my last email on 9th February 2019.
Also there is no more "Subscribe" button as it used to be.

There are quite a few questions related since this feature used to be popular.

It'd be great if SO provides a clear and definitive answer to this change.

Before with subscribe button:

[image]

Now:

[image]

Comment: It looks like that feature got unshipped. Instead create a filter: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254327/578411